# assigning values to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

If a have an array of pointers to an object, which way of filling the array is cleaner, (1) or (2), in the code segment below? Are

```
string ** list = new string*[5];
string* s = new string("foo");
*list[0] = *s;  //(1)
list[0] = s;   //(2)
```

Comment: None are cleaner - use std::vector.

Comment: (1) and (2) do different things, so it is hard to say which is "cleaner." I can tell you that (1) invokes undefined behavior. Can you describe what you intend the program to do?

Comment: @unapersson can you elaborate on this? I mean if the amount of data i want to store is constant, then whats wrong with using dynamic arrays?

Comment: Eh? I don't think you understand what vectors are - they are dynamic arrays managed for you by the compiler. which C++ text book are you using?

Comment: I do understand vectors, but I still don't see the benefit of it for constant amount of data

Comment: @user If it is a constant, then there is no need to create them dynamically at all. If you gave your real use case, we could probably advise you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method will result in undefined behaviour.  `list[0]` doesn't point at a valid `string` object, so dereferencing it and assigning to it will be bad.

The second method looks ok to me (in the sense that it won't have undefined behaviour), but I guess it depends on how you go on to use it.

Comment: "The first way will result in undefined behaviour" yes thats also what i thought, but somehow when i check the array content, it indeed stores a valid reference to s.

Comment: @user: It may *appear* to work, at least some of the time.  But in fact what will be happening is that you'll be trampling on some random section of memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without seeing the rest of your program, but both of this *seem* wrong. If "clean" is what you are looking for try either of these:

```
string * list = new string[5];
list[0] = "foo";
```

or

```
vector<string> list(5);
list[0] = "foo";
```

Both of these are (subjectively) cleaner than either of yours.

Comment: What is wrong with storing references to an object?
Why is it in your opinion cleaner to store the actual object in the array/vector?

Comment: @user: Better to ask what is right with unnecessary pointer manipulation?

Comment: because for example if my array is just partially filled, in can easily check, by storing pointers, which field actually point to elements and which are still unitiiliaized i.e. emtpy

Comment: For one thing, storing an array of pointers to allocated `string`s is less space-efficient than storing the `string`s themselves. But, more importantly, dynamically allocating an array of pointers to objects leads to bugs. As evidence of that, I offer your very question, in which you dereference and uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Thank you Rob, you convinced me.
Being a Java developer I'm never sure in C++ whether to store objects or references to objects in collections

Comment: But one question remains, if i have an array of objects in c++, then what is actually stored in the array? Do I store a copy of the existing object? Then it would be less space efficient then storing a pointer to it

Comment: Yes, an array of objects stores the objects themselves, not pointers to them. It happens that `std::string` is very small -- the same size as a pointer on my platform. Adding in the overhead that `new` imposes, it is cheaper to store the object. For significantly large objects, a different strategy might be better.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is an error, because list[0] is initially NULL, so you effectively wrote

```
*NULL = *s;
```

You should write instead

```
list[0] = new string;
*list[0] = *s;
```

or just

```
list[0] = new string(*s);
```

(2) is not an error, but *(list[0]) would exist only as long as *s exists.  If you change *s, then *(list[0]) changes also.  You also should delete either s or list[0] but not both.  Unless you really need this behaviour, (2) is ugly.

Generally, I don't see why do you need pointers here.  Therefore,

```
string* list = new string[5];
```

would be much cleaner, and

```
vector<string> list(5);
```

would be even better.

Finally, it is not a good idea to call something "list", since there is a standard container by this name.  (Neither call anything "vector", "set", "string", "stack", or "map").

Comment: Perhaps you meant "effectively" not "efficiently".